# Using openssl for email fetching throught shell script

Tags: shell, unix, openssl, expect

How can I use openssl for list printing of email messages in one command (shell script)?
I can open connection with:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect pop.gmail.com:995
```

The next step is pass user name and password:

```
USER myuser
PASS mypass
```

The next step is call LIST command

```
LIST
```

But how can I write shell script for this? I want use it in with **popen** function in my c sample program. Could you post example how I should use **expect** and **send** commands in shell script to do it?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work (you will maybe need to change it a bit):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn -console openssl blah blah blah blah
send "USER myuser\r"
send "PASS mypass\r"
send "LIST\r"
```

As simple as that. If you want to use popen, it will likely not work, because openssl requires interactive terminal, you need to somehow fake it. Expect can do that. Read the man page!